# How to create different layout for every wordpress category creating

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I've a single wordpress site.
I need a different layout for every cateogory.
Is any possible way to change layout for every category
For ex
I've a site named myname.com
i've categories criket, football, golf
in cricket my layout based blue color, sub menu arranged in horizontal
In football my layout based red color, sub menu arranged in vertical
In golf no submenu

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

Comment: @ArjanKnol thanks for comment, i think there explained how to change category page layout and content. my case change different layout for every category page...

Comment: You could do this with css, each category page receives a class, but you'll have lots of work there to make this work.

Comment: @NathanielFlick in my case i need single wordpress with different layout contents. any other options in wordpress

Comment: Category templates, and custom css are your ticket (see the Category Templates comment above)

Answer (score 0):

You can create templates for specific terms from a taxonomy by using this naming convention:

```
taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php
```

...so to create a template for an archive of posts with the category term "cricket", create the template:

```
taxonomy-category-cricket.php
```

...and for football:

```
taxonomy-category-football.php
```

Hope this helps...